# Making sure a character doesn't outshine others?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

This is based on [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58225/is-this-overpowered/58226?noredirect=1#comment122084_58226) question. How do I make sure a character like this doesn't overshadow others?

Comment: [Related] [What to do when your character is just too good?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/what-to-do-when-your-character-is-just-too-good)

Comment: Probably a duplicate but there's so little information it's hard to tell.  Speaking as a GM? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-to-handle-a-powergamer-munchkin is a dupe (and locked, for being similarly defined). As a player? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/what-to-do-when-your-character-is-just-too-good is a dupe.

Comment: Also related: [The tier system](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=5293) which should explain why your worries about a ranger with some minor buffs suddenly becoming OP are almost certainly unfounded.

Comment: Well, I didn't see the tier system yet. I didn't realize the ranger was seen as "tier 4" (AKA they suck by themselves) I thought basically "Everyone has a purpose and everyone has their place" The defender: (Fighter, paladin, etc.) The striker: (barbarian, rogue, ranger, monk) The Healer: (druid, favored soul, and cleric) and the mages: (wizard, warlock, and sorcerer) Thanks. I'm not as nervous about it now.

Comment: @CataruMoore The "Defender, Striker, Healer, Mage" role model isn't a bad starting point for understanding how classes work, but remember that builds can change *everything* - It's easy to make a mage who plays like a striker, or a healer who plays like a defender, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the best idea is to confront the players with a wide variety of obstacles that require different ways to overcome. It's not usually a problem if one character is really good in one type of situation, as long as he isn't the best all the time.